# Create custom page and custom menu

Tags: menus, wp-admin, dashboard

I'm trying to do one custom menu at my wordpress admin panel.

My plans are: make and menu, to add some contents at a custom page, like "people" and their names, etc...

I wanna make it with php.

I used this only to view whats happen:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page');

function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'manage_options', 'my-custom-submenu-page', 'my_custom_submenu_page_callback' ); 
}

function my_custom_submenu_page_callback() {
    echo '<h3>My Custom Submenu Page</h3>';

}
```

It added an page, inside tools menu, what can  I do to create on an exclusive menu??

On `my_custom_submenu_page_callback`, what can I do to work with embedded PHP code? like `mysql_query` and stuff?

Comment: 1) What does "create on an exclusive menu" mean? 2) "what can i do to work with embbed php code"? -- You know how PHP works, right? From another perspective, you ___already have___ "embedded" PHP on the page so what is the question?

Comment: @s_ha_dum exclusive menu i mean like this:
-Photos
  --Add Photos

Inserting like, mysql_query("blablabla") at submenu callback it will works?

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything? Do you mean something like "top-level menu"?

Comment: yeah yeah...i was missing this word..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, what you are doing is almost correct. You need [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) instead of `add_submenu_page`

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page');

function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_menu_page( 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'manage_options', 'my-custom-submenu-page', 'my_custom_submenu_page_callback' ); 
}

function my_custom_submenu_page_callback() {
    echo '<h3>My Custom Submenu Page</h3>';

}
```

As far as the "embedded" PHP, you already have it. Everything in that code is PHP. You can add whatever other PHP you want inside that callback (`my_custom_submenu_page_callback`) and it should work so long as the PHP itself is valid and you watch out for [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and such.

Your capability-- `manage_options`-- may need to be changed. That depends on how you want it to work.